# Product of two sets with density zero has density zero?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, asymptotics

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of $\mathbb N$ which have asymptotic density zero. Define $A\times B$ as the set of integers of the form $ab$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Must $A \times B$ also have asymptotic density zero?

I conjecture that it must , but I am not sure.

Comment: A suggestion: Let $A$ be the set of positive integers whose prime divisors are all equal to $1$ mod $3$, and let $B$ be the set of positive integers whose prime divisors are all equal to $2$ mod $3$. If these sets have asymptotic density zero, then we have a counterexample, because $A \times B = \mathbb N$. Does anybody know whether $A$ and $B$ have asymptotic density zero?

Comment: (Contd.) See Problem 14.12 at [this link](https://books.google.de/books?id=NaACAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA391&ots=QK5m7j3DrK&pg=PA390#v=onepage&q&f=false): "to justify that most even numbers have a prime factor $p \equiv 2$ mod $3$..." (Of course, all even numbers have such a factor, namely $p=2$; I assume the author means "an _odd_ prime factor $p \equiv 2$ mod $3$.") That would seem to take care of $A$, but what about $B$?

Comment: A small mistake: my $A \times B$ is not the whole of $\mathbb N$; it consists of all numbers not divisible by $3$. So it has asymptotic density $\frac23$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the set of primes $P$ into two sets $A_p,B_p$ by considering the partial products of $(1-1/2)(1-1/3)(1-1/5)\cdots$ with each factor of the form $1-1/p$ where the primes $p$ run through the sequence $2,3,5,\cdots$ of primes. We alternately go for partial products each at most $1/2,$ so that $A_p$ begins with $2$ [since $1-1/2\le 1/2$] and then $B_p$ continues with $3,5,7$ since $(1-1/3)(1-1/5)(1-1/7)=16/35=0.45...$ but using only $3,5$ is not enough for the first $B_p$ group [$(1-1/3)(1-1/5)=8/15=0.53...$ is not at most $1/2$]

We are assured that we never reach a point where we cannot make the next $A_p$ or $B_p$ group of primes have their partial product of $1-1/p$ terms at most $1/2,$ since the product of this expression over all primes $p$ diverges to $0$. If my calculation is right, then the next group of primes in list $A_p$ begins with $11$ and ends with $83$

Now we define the subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{N}$ so that $A$ consists of all positive integers which may be formed using only the prime factors (to whatever powers) from $A_p$, and similarly $B$ is the integers formable using only powers of primes from $B_p$

It then is clear at least that $AB$ is all of $\mathbb{N},$ while arguments similar to that showing the natural density of primes is zero using the full product of the factors $1-1/p$ seem to me to show that each of the above $A,B$ have density zero. (I intend to return to this last issue with more details, but thought I'd put this admittedly partial answer up for now, maybe someone could help finish it, or show the $A,B$ had positive densities after all, then I'd delete.)

Here at any rate is a *heuristic* attempt to show e.g. that the natural density of $A$ is zero. A positive integer is in $A$ iff none of its prime divisors lie in the set $B_p$ of primes. The latter were chosen in such a way that the product of terms $(1-1/p)$ for $p \in B_p$ is zero, since we have partial products bounded by $1/2,$ then further by $(1/2)^2,$ etc. And in a probability sense, $(1-1/p)$ is the likelihood that a "random" integer is not divisible by $p.$ So if we believe such probability arguments, we can say the probability of a positive integer *not* being divisible by a prime in the set $B_p$ is zero, which is to say the probability of a positive integer to lie in set $A$ is also zero.

Comment: Hmm: even though an upvote happened, However I'm in doubt now about whether the sets $A,B$ constructed have natural density $0$. It seems the set of squarefree positive integers has positive natural density $6/\Pi^2$ and it also seems one could jam these by a coding process into one of the sets $A,B.$

Comment: My attempts to re-code the squarefree integers into one or the other of the above $A,B$ involved moving blocks of them to the right by uncontrollable amounts, which means the natural density could easily change from being positive to winding up zero.

Comment: I think your premise is sound. I don't see why the squarefree integers pose a problem: most of them contain factors from both $A_p$ and $B_p$, so are not in either $A$ or $B$.

Comment: The set of numbers with prime divisors only in $A_p$ is the set of numbers *not divisible* by any prime in $E :=  \mathbb{P}\setminus A_p$. The natural density of numbers not divisible by any prime in $E$ is $$\prod_{p\in E} \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p}\biggr).$$ Therefore both sets, $A$ and $B$, have indeed natural density $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for this comment, which fills in where I only gave a hand-waving heuristic. Is there a reference for the natural density result you mention, which would be then be good to include in the answer?

Comment: I'm sure there are (lots of) references, but I don't know any, I'm not good at literature. For any finite set $F$ of primes, it's easy to see that the natural density is $\prod_{p\in F} (1-p^{-1})$ - generally, the natural density of numbers coprime to $n$ is $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$. Thus for every finite $F\subset E$, $$\prod_{p\in F} \biggl(1-\frac{1}{p}\biggr) \geqslant N(A).$$ Since here we picked $A_p$ and $B_p$ so that the corresponding products are both $0$, that suffices. If we had a positive product, it would take some work to show the density is not smaller than the product.